# kill threads later a time in python

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, subprocess

I have a python code with threads, and i need that if in for example 1 hour the threads are not finished, finish all threads and finish the script, and if the hour are not complete wait that all my threads finish.

I try with a daemon thread, and with a sleep of the hour, and if the hour is complete use a: `sys.exit()` but it not works to me, because always wait to my sleep threadh, then my script wait until the thread finished and the `sys.exit()` does not work.

```
import socket, threading, time, sys
from sys import argv
import os

acc_time=0
transactions_ps=5

ins = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
msisdn_list = []
for line in ins:
    msisdn_list.append (line.strip('\n'))
   # print line
ins.close()


def worker(msisdn_list):
    semaphore.acquire()
    global transactions_ps
    print "  *****  ", threading.currentThread().getName(), "Lanzado"
    count=1
    acc_time=0
    print "len: ",len(msisdn_list)
    for i in msisdn_list:
        try:
            init=time.time()
            time.sleep(2)
            print "sleeping...",i
            time.sleep(4)
            final=time.time()
            acc_time = acc_time+final-init
            print acc_time
        except IOError:
                print "Connection failed",sys.exc_info()[0]

    print "Deteniendo ",threading.currentThread().getName()
    semaphore.release()
def kill_process(secs_to_die):
    time.sleep(secs_to_die)
    sys.exit()

seconds_to_die=3600

thread_kill = threading.Thread(target = kill_process, args=(seconds_to_die,))
thread_kill.start()

max_con=5
semaphore = threading.BoundedSemaphore(max_con)
for i in range(0,28,transactions_ps):
    w = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(msisdn_list[i:i+transactions_ps-1],))
    w.setDaemon(True)
    w.start()
```

How can to do it

Comment: This code works fine for me - it waits until `secs_do_die` has passed, then the whole script exits. Is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: `with open(sys.argv[1]) as file: msisdn_list = file.read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 2):

A minimal change to your code that would fix the issue is `threading.Barrier`:

```
barrier = Barrier(number_of_threads, timeout=3600)
# create (number_of_threads - 1) threads, pass them barrier
# each thread calls barrier.wait() on exit
barrier.wait() # after number_of_threads .wait() calls or on timeout it returns
```

A simpler alternative is to use `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` that creates daemon threads:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads

start = timer()
endtime = start + 3600
for result in pool.imap_unordered(work, args):
    if timer() > endtime:
       exit("timeout")
```

The code doesn't timeout until a work item is done i.e., it expects that processing a single item from the list doesn't take long.

Complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from time import monotonic as timer, sleep

info = mp.get_logger().info

def work(i):
    info("start %d", i)
    sleep(1)
    info("end %d", i)

seconds_to_die = 3600
max_con = 5
mp.log_to_stderr().setLevel(logging.INFO) # enable logging
pool = Pool(max_con) # no more than max_con at a time
start = timer()
endtime = start + seconds_to_die
for _ in pool.imap_unordered(work, range(10000)):
    if timer() > endtime:
        exit("timeout")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this implementation of KThread:

http://python.todaysummary.com/q_python_45717.html

Comment: You should add some information to your answer that summarizes what's being said in link you included. Otherwise, this answer will become useless if that link ever dies. Alternatively, just add this as a comment to the question.